# How to have common threads

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, wildfly-10

I have an API (javaee / wildfly) with several endpoints like that (I used only two but in the end, there will be more) :

- User access EndpointA and trigger : Thread shortProcessA (trigger Thread  longProcessA in background) -> shortProcessA ends
- User access EndpointB and trigger : Thread shortProcessB (trigger Thread longProcessB in background) -> shortProcessB ends

My question is regarding longProcessB that should start only when longProcessA has finished and persist the state success in DB

My first thought was : using a while loop longProcessB wait for longProcessA state success in DB ... but I don't like it ...
I would like more something regarding the thread state : longProcessB wait for longProcessA to say that its process is finished but is it possible ?

EDIT:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<Object> c = Executors.callable(new Task());
executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(c), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.shutdown();
```

Then in my Task (I set the name Import to the thread) :

```
Thread thread = getThreadByName("Import");      
if (thread!= null) {
    while (thread.isAlive() == true) {
        try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `java.util.concurrent` package's `ExecutorService` with `Future` object  to manage multiple thread.

Comment: I've tried to use ExecutorService my longProcessA is executed in a new thread "import" it's ok but I don't find a way to get the Future object from my longProcessB, the only thing I've achieved is to find my thread "import" using its name and wait with a while its end ... (see code on my original post)

Comment: Have a look at the [Java EE Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/concurrency-utilities.htm) utilities.